# MySQL String replacement with multiple values?

Tags: mysql

```
    ClosedAccount[TABLE] values .

    |---------SERVICES-------------|

    ACCOUNTS,DOCS,BOOKS,READER
    BOOKS,ACCOUTNS,CALENDAR,READER
```

QUERY

I Want to exclude "ACCOUNTS,BOOKS,READER" from two rows . This order is not properly maintained .

Trivial Solution :

Select REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(services,"ACCOUNTS",""),"DOCS",""),"READER","") from  ClosedAccount;

I want to optmize this . Is there any solution avialable please suggest .

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to remove those *strings*, then I believe you've already got the answer since it's string manipulation that you're after, not search criteria for rows.